# how can I use persian language text in pyautogui library

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to fill some fields using pyautogui library
But the problem is that when I want to fill the fields in Persian language, it is not done
How should I solve the problem of this library in the Persian language?
I don't even know if the problem is with this library or with my Python because this library works well for the English language

my code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(x=36, y=52)
pyautogui.write("Hello World") #This part works well
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write("سلام دنیا")  #This part does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyautogui` library doesn't support languages except English. As recommended on this [post](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/237#issue-334362962) you can use `pyperclip` in addition to `pyautogui`:

```
import pyperclip
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.click(x=36, y=52)
pyautogui.write("Hello World") #This part works well
pyautogui.press('tab')

content = "سلام دنیا"

pyperclip.copy(content)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Comment: Pyperclip is the perfect solution. I don't know why you need sleep.